# DocuSign eSignature How to create advanced dashboards/reports metrics using another software product? For example: MS SSRS, and/or Power BI

Tags: docusignapi

The problem is that DocuSign does not provide the reporting capabilities/tools my users are demanding. They need "one source" Dashboards/Data that indicates the "Action" where an envelope sent is in the workflow of the template.
For example:

**Step 1**
Envelope was sent to recipient 1 for signature (action= signed/completed date)

**Step 2**
Envelope was sent to recipient 2 for signature (action= signed/completed date, or waiting on others)
And/or
Envelope was sent to recipient 3 for signature (action= signed/completed date, or waiting on others)

**Step 3**
Envelope sent in action/status= completed, voided, etc.

I tried all the existing standards reports, and none of them provided a "one source/report" solution.

Answer (score 0):

The event reporting you've listed in your question are available via the Connect webhook eSign feature from DocuSign. It makes HTTPS calls to your server when those events (and others) occur. Your server can then store the events in your BI database for later analysis and reporting.

See the [Connect webhooks documentation](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=zko1583277388422.html&_LANG=enus)

Comment: Fantastic news! I will check the feature. Thank you for your help!